# event.stopPropagation() not working on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

When clicking on modal window body, it runs outer div's onClick handler. `event.stoppropagation()` working fine for button inside outer div and buttons inside modal but don't know how to unbind outer div click handler on modal body.

[sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/event-propagation-bug-izibh) (Modal is not working on csb, please run on your code editor)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleShow = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setShow(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setShow(false);
  };

  const deleteModal = () => {
    return (
      <Modal
        id="deleteModal"
        className="modal"
        show={show}
        onHide={handleClose}
        centered
        size="sm"
        backdrop="static"
        keyboard={false}
      >
        <Modal.Body>
          <div>
            <span>Delete Tweet ?</span>
          </div>
          <div>This can’t be undone</div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary">Delete</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  };

  const postHandler = () => {
    alert("clicked on div");
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={postHandler} style={{ border: "1px solid" }}>
      {deleteModal()}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Button variant="info" onClick={handleShow}>
        Delete
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

P.S- I'm using `react-bootstrap` for creating modal.

Comment: One possible solution could be to attach event handler to your modal and using `event.stopPropagation();` to prevent event from bubbling.

Comment: @HassanImam How can I bind events on a modal dialog because modal is simple HTML?

Comment: In the Modal component, you can attach a onClick handler and there you can use `event.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 return (
    <>
      {show && deleteModal()}    // just move this logic outside the div
      <div onClick={postHandler} style={{ border: '1px solid' }}>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Button variant="info" onClick={handleShow}>
          Delete
        </Button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Hey, if you just move the `deleteModal` outside the div then it would solve your problem.